# Message passing with parent handle not reaching

Tags: delphi, windows-messages

In a new project, I created a MainForm with 2 panels, and a Form with a button.

I added this code on the MainForm:

```
interface

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
     procedure OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_FILEREADY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

uses
  PannelForm;

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(self) do
  try
    parent := panel2;
    borderstyle := bsNone;
    InnerHandle := self.Handle;
    Show;

  finally

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  showmessage('got event');
end;
```

And this code on the Form with a button:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    InnerHandle:HWND;
  end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//  PostMessage(Application.Mainform.Handle, WM_FILEREADY, 0, 0); // works
//  PostMessage(Application.Handle, WM_FILEREADY, 0, 0); // not working
//  PostMessage(parent.Handle, WM_FILEREADY, 0, 0); // not working
  PostMessage(InnerHandle, WM_FILEREADY, 0, 0); // works

end;
```

My question is: when calling the first and forth version, everything is fine.

What is missing in the third version that is not working?

Why doesn't Parent contain the right handle? Isn't it the (part of) point of passing a Parent?

Comment: Window recreation will burn you. Use AllocateHWnd. Or TThread.Synchronize.Queue.

Comment: "Typically, this method is used to create non-visual windows that respond to messages" so AllocateHWnd is not for this case. http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_AllocateHWnd.html and why should TThread be used? could you point to a link to explain the issue , or explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented message handling in `TForm1`, but `Form2.Parent.Handle` is not `Form1.Handle` instead you have assigned `Panel2.Handle` to it.

Each windowed control has its own handle. So your panels have different handles than your form and they cannot process messages that are implemented in Form class.

Everything works as it should, even though it is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `Parent` to be `Form1.Panel2`, not `Form1` itself.  Your message handler will only receive messages that are posted to `Form1` directly.  Your other calls are posting to `Form1.Handle`, which is why they work.

If you want to post the message to `Parent.Handle` when `Parent` is not `Form1`, you will have to subclass the Panel you are assigning as `Parent`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
     DefPanelWndProc: TWndMethod;
     procedure PanelWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DefPanelWndProc := Panel2.WindowProc;
  Panel2.WindowProc := PanelWndProc;

  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Parent := Panel2;
  Form2.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.PanelWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_FILEREADY then
    ShowMessage('got event')
  else
    DefPanelWndProc(Msg);
end;
```

Otherwise, post the message to `Form1` instead.

If you post using the `Form1.Handle` property each time, everything will be fine (I am not counting multi-threaded code, as `TWinControl.Handle` is not thread-safe).  However, if you cache the value of `Form1.Handle` to a variable and then post using that variable, your code will stop working if `Form1.Handle` is recreated (which can and does happen).  In that case, you need to detect the recreation and update the variable accordingly:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  private
     procedure OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_FILEREADY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Parent := Panel2;
  Form2.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Form2.InnerHandle := Self.Handle;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if Form2 <> nil then
    Form2.InnerHandle := Self.Handle;
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWnd;
begin
  if Form2 <> nil then
    Form2.InnerHandle := 0;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage('got event');
end;
```

Otherwise, don't use `Form1.Handle` at all. Use a different window that will never be recreated.

You can use `AllocateHWnd()` to create a dedicated window:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
     MsgWnd: HWND;
     procedure MsgWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgWnd := AllocateHWnd(MsgWndProc);

  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Parent := Panel2;
  Form2.Borderstyle := bsNone;
  Form2.InnerHandle := MsgWnd;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MsgWnd <> 0 then
    DeallocateHWnd(MsgWnd);
end;

procedure TForm1.MsgWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_FILEREADY then
    ShowMessage('got event')
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(MsgWnd, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;
```

Or you can use the `Application.Handle` window:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
     function AppWndProc(var Msg: TMessage): Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HookMainWindow(AppWndProc);

  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Parent := Panel2;
  Form2.Borderstyle := bsNone;
  Form2.InnerHandle := Application.Handle;
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
```

Application.UnhookMainWindow(AppWndProc);
    end;

```
function TForm1.AppWndProc(var Msg: TMessage): Boolean:
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_FILEREADY then
  begin
    ShowMessage('got event');
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;
```